# Pihole only resolves clients names on IPv4

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, software-installation, dns, pi-hole

I have setup Pihole on my Pi and evrything works except the client resolvement.
Ipv4 adresses get resolved in the certain names i have set in my Router but IPv6 adresses dont get set.
I have set ULA to be always used. [image: Pihole settings]
My Router is a FritzBox and i have set dns server for ipv4 and ipv6.

On my PC:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> -t AAAA google.de

;; global options: +cmd

;; Got answer:

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50519

;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1



;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:

; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1452

;; QUESTION SECTION:

;google.de. IN AAAA



;; ANSWER SECTION:

google.de. 300 IN AAAA 2a00:1450:400e:809::2003



;; Query time: 250 msec

;; SERVER: 192.168.178.202#53(192.168.178.202)

;; WHEN: Sat Mar 21 22:18:26 CET 2020

;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 75
```

```
Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: fritz.box

DHCP-aktiviert: Ja

IPv4-Standardgateway: 192.168.178.1

IPv4-DHCP-Server: 192.168.178.1

IPv4-DNS-Server: 192.168.178.202

IPv6-Standardgateway: fe80::2e3a:fdff:fe01:a194%21

IPv6-DNS-Server: fd00::e3dc:6d8d:447c:26dc
```

How do i get it to resolve also IPv6 Clients?